# Can I bypass installing glibc.i686 as a dependency when I already have the x86_64 version?

Tags: fedora, dependency-management, atom-editor

I'm trying to install Atom from the official RPM provided. libXss.so.1 is a dependency and tries to install the 32-bit version of glibc when I already have the 64-bit version. It then conflicts with the 2.23.1-7 older version of glibc that I already have.

So where do I go from here? I'm guessing that there is a bugfix somewhere in libXss. libXss tries to install i686 arch for all it's dependencies.

I'm using Fedora 24 x86_64

### Terminal Output

sudo rpm -ivh atom.x86_64.rpm

```
 error: Failed dependencies:
      libXss.so.1 is needed by atom-1.13.0-0.1.x86_64
```

sudo dnf install libXss.so.1

```
 Error: Transaction check error:
     file /usr/share/doc/glibc/NEWS from install of glibc-2.23.1-11.fc24.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64
```

sudo dnf install glibc-2.23.1-11.fc.24.x86_64

```
 Package glibc-2.23.1-11.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
 Dependencies resolved.
 Nothing to do.
 Complete!
```

#### Secondary/Unimportant Question

Do I need glibc-2.23.1-**7**.fc24.x86_64 when I already have glibc-2.23.1-**11**.fc24.x86_64? I see that I have both installed yet I have no conflict problems.

### edit

I gave up and decided to install from the copr repo

```
sudo dnf copr enable mosquito/atom
sudo dnf install atom

Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libkadm5clnt_mit.so.10.0 from install of libkadm5-1.14.4-4.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-libs-1.14.1-6.fc24.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libkadm5srv_mit.so.10.0 from install of libkadm5-1.14.4-4.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-libs-1.14.1-6.fc24.x86_64
```

What is going on?

Comment: Install the 64 bit version of `libXss`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I did that before posting. It made no difference. What I would need is to somehow tell atom to use the 64bit libXss library as the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I bypass installing glibc.i686 as a dependency when I already have the x86_64 version?

Not if you need to install 32-bit software — you'll need the 32-bit libs for that. 64-bit libraries aren't supersets of the 32-bit ones.

> I'm trying to install Atom from the official RPM provided. libXss.so.1 is a dependency and tries to install the 32-bit version of glibc when I already have the 64-bit version. It then conflicts with the 2.23.1-7 older version of glibc that I already have.

This is a frequent problem. **Installing 32-bit versions of packages without updating to the latest versions of the main 64-bit packages is not supported.** Upgrade first, then install.

> Do I need glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64 when I already have glibc-2.23.1-11.fc24.x86_64? I see that I have both installed yet I have no conflict problems.

This can happen if there's an interrupted upgrade transaction. You should be able to `dnf remove glibc-2.23.1-7.fc24.x86_64` safely. If that gives you errors, time to stop and make sure nothing else is wrong. Or, you can really just ignore it — next time a new glibc update comes out, it should replace *both*.

> I gave up and decided to install from the copr repo

The errors you see here are actually the same root problem as trying to install 32-bit packages without updating first. RPMs can share files, as long as they are completely identical. That's true in matched versions of the various kerberos packages, but not true if there's a mismatch, and the dependency information doesn't handle this. So, again **upgrade to latest packages before installing new ones**.